# Creating a predicate for my model in sqllite and ios 7

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios7, nspredicate

I have a model like so:

```
Users
Attribute
email (is unique)
Relationships
friendsOfUser

Friends
Attribute
active (yes or no)
email (is unique with combination of freindsToUser)
Relationship
friendsToUser
```

How do I create the predicate to find all the active friends of a user if friendsOfUser and friendsToUser are a many-to-many relationship?

The code is as follows:

```
entity = [NSEntityDescription
              entityForName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Friends class]]
              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" ? ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all active friends of a user, the following fetch request should work:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Friends"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"active = YES AND ANY friendsToUser = %@", theUser];
request.predicate = predicate;
```

*Remark:* I would call the entities "User" and "Friend" because each instance represents
a single user or friend.